# Color Geotiff read as Grayscale

Tags: c++, image, libtiff, geotiff

I have some code for reading geotiff files which involves the use of the `TIFFReadRGBAStrip` routine (libtiff library).

Most of the tifs are handled successfully and the image data is as expected, however there are several files which are coming out as `grayscale (58 58 58 ff 6b 6b 6b ff.....)` even though I believe they are color 
Note: I've loaded the same files into GLobal Mapper and although a message appears regarding the 4th band they are displayed as color.

The configuration details of these files are:

```
TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE = 8
TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL = 3
TIFFTAG_SAMPLEFORMAT = 1 (SAMPLEFORMAT_UINT)
TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC = 1 (PHOTOMETRIC_MINISBLACK)
```

I've obtained the latest version of the libtiff, proj4 and libgeotiff libraries and rebuilt them but to no avail.

Any advice on why this is occurring would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How about posting a link to one of them so we can experiment?